# Async JavaScript: problem with undefined value

Tags: asynchronous, promise

I have to write a function that receives a json, loops into it, takes some value from that to make an axios request to an api, takes some parameter from the api response and adds it to the json received in input. Here is the current code:

```
let db_mock = require('../db_mock.json');

function Geolocation(db_mock: any): any {

    for (let i: number = 0; i < db_mock.length; i++) {

        if (db_mock[i].place == null) {
            console.log('ERRORE: Manca l\'indicazione del luogo');
            return;
        }

        for (let j: number = 0; j < db_mock[i].place.length; j++) {
            axios.get(URL)
            .then((response: any) => {
                db_mock[i].place[j] = {
                    city: response.data.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.Address.City,
                    country: response.data.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.Address.Country,
                    county: response.data.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.Address.County,
                    label: response.data.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.Address.Label,
                    postalCode: response.data.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.Address.PostalCode,
                    state: response.data.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.Address.State,
                    position: {
                        latitude: response.data.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.DisplayPosition.Latitude, 
                        longitude: response.data.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.DisplayPosition.Longitude 
                    }
                }
            })
            .catch((error: any) => console.log(error))
        }

    }

}

let db: any = Geolocation(db_mock);

// console.log(db);
```

The problem is that when I try to get the modified json and console log it, it is undefined. I can't figure out how to handle this async object.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your `Geolocation` function doesn't even have a `return` statement?

Comment: When I put a return in the .then it gives error and if I put it outside it returns the json not modified.

Comment: Yes, since it is asynchronous you must return a promise for the results. Use `Promise.all` to wait for all the concurrent axios calls,

Comment: Sorry but I'm pretty new to asynchronous programming and promises and I don't know how to integrate `Promise.all` into the code. I will do some experiment.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to solve the problem!

Here is my solution for those interested:

```
function Geolocation(db_mock: any) {

    const promises: any[] = [];

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        for (let i: number = 0; i < db_mock.length; i++) {

            if (db_mock[i].place == null) {
                reject(new Error("Manca l'indicazione del luogo"));
            }

            for (let j: number = 0; j < db_mock[i].place.length; j++) {
                promises.push(
                    axios.get(`https://geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/search/6.2/geocode.json?searchtext=${db_mock[i].place[j]}&apiKey=${process.env.API_KEY}`)
                    .then((response: any) => {
                        db_mock[i].place[j] = {
                            city: response.data.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.Address.City,
                            country: response.data.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.Address.Country,
                            county: response.data.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.Address.County,
                            label: response.data.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.Address.Label,
                            postalCode: response.data.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.Address.PostalCode,
                            state: response.data.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.Address.State,
                            position: {
                                latitude: response.data.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.DisplayPosition.Latitude, 
                                longitude: response.data.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.DisplayPosition.Longitude 
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .catch((error: any) => reject(new Error(error)))
                )
            }

        }

        Promise.all(promises)
        .then(_ => resolve(db_mock) )
        .catch(err => reject(new Error(err)))
    })

}

Geolocation(db_mock)
.then(res => console.log(res))
.catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Thanks to user Bergi for the help!